# view multi-dimensional array values debugging in Visual C++

Tags: arrays, debugging, visual-c++

I'm trying to debug some C++ code but I can't see the values in a multi-dimensional array while debugging

I have a dynamically allocated pointer (double **A).

When I try to watch the value of this array I just get the first value, I can't see the remaining values.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Is this really a multi-dimensional array or is it an array of arrays?

Comment: it's an array of arrays. Was not aware of a difference

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to see large data arrays in VS is to use a memory window instead of a Watch window or the Autos or Locals window.  Just drag your pointer value to the memory window's address box.

Comment: This actually solves the problem, don't know why it is not selected as an answer...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Visual Studio, put array[X],Y in the watch window, where X is the line number and Y the number of rows - this will allow you to watch whole lines in the watch window.

For example, put those lines to the watch window:

```
array[0],7
array[1],7
array[2],7
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through and print out each value. Roughly something like this:

```
void print2DArray(double **A, int width, int height) {
    for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
            cout<<A[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through the debugger you may write explicitly in the watch window `A[2][1]` etc..

**Edited - after the code presented:**

```
int main() {
    double **A; 
    double M = 4;
    A = new double *[M]; //define M by M matrix
    for( int k =0; k < M; k++) { 
        A[k] = new double [M]; 
    } 
    //assign values to matrix 
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) { 
            if ( j == i) { 
                A[i][j] = 2; 
            } else { 
                A[i][j] = 1; 
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I put break point on the `return 0` and add some test values to the watch window:

```
    A[0][0] 2.0000000000000000  double
    A[0][1] 1.0000000000000000  double
    A[0][2] 1.0000000000000000  double
    A[1][0] 1.0000000000000000  double
    A[1][1] 2.0000000000000000  double
    A[1][2] 1.0000000000000000  double
```

It seems fine. What do you get when you're doing the same? Where is the problem?
You can also print the values to screen as *MatrixFrog* suggested.

Comment: That doesn't work. I get the values of the first row only
so A[0][0] = A[1][0]=A[2][0] and so on. The array is:
2 1 1

1 2 1

1 1 2

So this is clearly wrong. I'm starting to question my decision not use C# for this.

Comment: That's very odd. I think you should post the whole code of creating and populating the array.

Comment: there you go:

double **A;
 double m;
 A = new double *[M];

 //define M by M matrix
  for( int k =0; k < M; k++)
  {
  A[k] = new double [M];
  }
    
    //assign values to matrix
 for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
   {  
    if ( j == i)
    {
     A[i][j] = 2;
    }
    else
    {
     A[i][j] = 1;
    }

   
   }

Comment: My problem is that I don't get what I should, instead I get A[0][0]=A[1][0] =2 ; A[0][1]=A[1][1] = 1 and so on. In fact, I just stepped through watching all values of A, while assigning the values w and A[1][0] gets assigned at the same time as A[0][0]. This is driving me insane. Help!!!! :)

Comment: Try to run **exactly** the code I posted. It's complete program; run this in new empty project. Does it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get: http://www.flickr.com/photos/42475383@N03/4247049191/

edit.

I was using a CLR console project. I tried a win32 console and it works fine. I can see a google moment coming up to find out what a CLR project is.