# C - Debugging a particular sub array of 2D arrays

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I am writing a C program in VS 2013 and I want to debug a particular sub-array from full 2D matrix of ints. For example, using debugger watch window, I can print like,

```
Mat        // this shows the full NxM Mat matrix values
Mat[i][j]  // this shows value of cell (i, j)
Mat[i]     // this shows the values of full i'th row
Mat[i], j  // this shows first j values from i'th row
```

But I want to print a snapshot of a sub-part of Mat, which consists of (i1, j1) to (i2, j2) in small 2D grid. Is it possible? I require it because sometimes debugging smaller sub-array seems a tedious work especially when the main array is too big and I am interested to a subpart somewhere in the bottom-right corner of the full array.

Any workaround, if there is no standard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want with one command, but maybe you could work this out based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457935/2411320), where he mentions that:

```
Mat + 100, 10
```

which will show the 10 elements starting at `Mat[100]`. You don't want that, but if you could play around and get the elements at `j1`, then you could combine them to get a subarray, maybe.

PS: Give the memory window a try too, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1982304/2411320).

Comment: Thanks. Where can I get the Memory Window?

Comment: You are welcome @SazzadHissainKhan, I don't have VS studio now, so I just googled and got [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx). Hope that helps, cheers!